# Is there an example of simple Django client server model?

Tags: python, django, web-applications, client-server

I am novice in Python and totally new to Django. This is my requirement. My browser will show a form with 10 questions and user has to mark Yes/No. Once the user submits the form - it should start learning model at backend (written in python using sklearn) and use the data labelled by user. For next iteration if the model needs more training data - the browser should show 10 more questions for the user to label.

Once the user label - learning model should continue and this process should repeat until we have a learning module.

I saw many web pages and documents and the pointer was to use Django web framework for python. I am having a hard time finding an example or as to how to approach this problem. My backend learning module should pause when user is labeling the data and should continue once user hits submit on the form data (web page) otherwise i will have to maintain state and that's an overhead.

Any suggestions, pointers, links or examples will surely help.

Comment: A great example of how to configure a Django client (view & form) / server (model) is available here.  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial01/#creating-the-polls-app You could tie your learning model into the form validation to achieve the flow you are looking for. Could you be more specific an what you would like clarified?

Comment: Even after reading it several timed: I don't understand your 'maintain state' assumption.